# linux / bash parse through json-like data

Tags: json, linux, parsing, awk, sed

Here is some data that I have:

```
animal { 
    dog {
        body {
            parts {
                legs = old
                brain = average
                tail= curly
                }
   
            }
        }
    cat {
        body {
            parts {
                legs = new
                brain = average
                tail {
                    base=hairy
                    tip=nothairy
                }
   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the data is not really json as it has the following rules:

- supports `=` or `=` between key and value pairs.
- No `"` or `,` throughout the data. separation of data is based on new line.

Is it even possible to parse this with awk or sed? I tried `jq` but it does not work as this isn't really true json data.

My goal is to display only "dog" and "cat". Based on them being the top values under "animal".

```
$ some-magical-command
dog
cat
```

Comment: Just displaying `dog` and `cat` is quite simple; you could even do it in bash. But is that really the limit of your requirements? In case it is, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you currently want and for ease of any future manipulation of your data, you could use any POSIX `awk` (for character classes) to convert your structure to JSON and then use `jq` on it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { print "{" }
!NF { next }
{
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    gsub(/[[:alnum:]_]+/,"\"&\"")
    gsub(/ *= */,": ")
    sub(/" *{/,"\": {")
}
(++nr) > 1 {
    sep = ( /"/ && (prev ~ /["}]$/) ? "," : "" )
    printf "%s%s%s", prev, sep, ORS
}
{ prev = $0 }
END { print prev ORS "}" }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{
"animal": {
    "dog": {
        "body": {
            "parts": {
                "legs": "old",
                "brain": "average",
                "tail": "curly"
                }
            }
        },
    "cat": {
        "body": {
            "parts": {
                "legs": "new",
                "brain": "average",
                "tail": {
                    "base": "hairy",
                    "tip": "nothairy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Current and some possible future uses:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | jq -r '.animal | keys[]'
cat
dog
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | jq -r '.animal.dog.body.parts | keys[]'
brain
legs
tail
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | jq -r '.animal.dog.body.parts'
{
  "legs": "old",
  "brain": "average",
  "tail": "curly"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | jq -r '.animal.cat.body.parts'
{
  "legs": "new",
  "brain": "average",
  "tail": {
    "base": "hairy",
    "tip": "nothairy"
  }
}
```

The above assumes your input always looks as shown in your question.

Comment: This is really awesome. However be aware, if there are ip addresses "10.10.10.10/24", every integer between octets gets quotes, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Change `[[:alnum:]_]` in `gsub(/[[:alnum:]_]+/,"\"&\"")` to be whatever regexp you want to match the strings to be quoted, e.g. `gsub(/[[:alnum:]_.\/]+/,"\"&\"")` would accommodate the `.`s and `/` in your IP address and if there's other characters just include them too. That's what I mean at the bottom by "The above assumes your input always looks as shown in your question." - the script isn't parsing your input as tokens of a language, it's just matching the kinds of text that look like the text you provided in your input.

Answer (score 1):

It's *fairly* close to [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) syntax, if you feel like learning a new language.

```
set data {
    animal { 
        dog {
            body {
                parts {
                    legs = old
                    brain = large
                    tail= curly
                    }
       
                }
            }
        cat {
            body {
                parts {
                    legs = new
                    brain = tiny
                    tail {
                        base=hairy
                        tip=nothairy
                    }
       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

set data [regsub -line -all {\s*=\s*(.+)} $data { "\1"}]

dict get $data animal dog body parts brain    ;# => large
```

I know some people who would argue about your classification of dog brains vs cat brains...

Comment: hmm, I get "Command 'dict' not found, but can be installed" do I require another application to run these commands? Again trying to do everything via bash.
Re: brain size, I agree, I updated my post.

Comment: This is Tcl code so needs to be run in a Tcl interpreter: `tclsh`

Comment: bash does not have arbitrarily deeply nested data structures. Your data indicates bash is an insufficient tool to meet your needs.

Comment: That is what I thought, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the recommendations. I wont be able to use anything outside of bash though unfortunately.

Comment: @dave: your question seems to imply that awk is also a possibility. Is that true? And if so, is it OK to rely on Gnu awk?

Comment: @rici, sure! I only mentioned it because I read online that you could parse through JSON with awk and sed, just couldn't get it to work on the data I shared. Then again, I am not the best awk / sed developer.

Comment: @Dave you can parse JSON with GNU awk using it's JSON extension, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawkextlib.html, but as you pointed out your data isn't JSON so that's no more useful than jq. You can't parse JSON with sed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the second-level keys, and you're not too concerned about producing good error messages for erroneous inputs, then it's pretty straight-forward. The basic idea is this:

1. There are three formats for an input line:

   - ID {
   - ID = value    # where the = might not be space-separated
   - }
2. As the lines are read, we keep track of nesting depth by incrementing a counter with the first line type and decrementing it with the third line type.
3. When the nesting counter is 1, if the line has an `ID` field, we print it.

That can be done quite simply with an awk script. This script should be saved in a file with a name like `level2_keys.awk`; you can then execute the command `awk -f level2_keys.awk /path/to/input/file`. Note that all the rules end with `next;` to avoid rules following a match being evaluated.

```
$1 == "}"    { # Decrement nesting on close
               --nesting;
               next;
             }
/=/          { # Remove the if block if you don't want to print these keys.
               if (nesting == 1) {
                 gsub("=", " = ");    # Force = to be a field
                 print($1);
               }
               next;
             }
$2 == "{"    { # Increment nesting (and maybe print) on open
               if (nesting == 1) print($1);
               ++nesting;
               next;
             }
# NF is non-zero if the line is not blank.
NF           { print "Bad input at " NR ": '"$0"'" > "/dev/stderr"; }
```